# Use cases for metadata in Clojure

Tags: clojure, metadata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some of the usage of Meta Data in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175258/what-are-some-of-the-usage-of-meta-data-in-clojure)

What are good use cases for metadata in Clojure? (Would you for example use it as a substitute for types?) I would love to see some useful examples using metadata.

Comment: Note that alot of the examples (for examle #^String) are old and shouldn't be used like this any more.