# Importing scripts at runtime

Tags: reflection, import, clojure, namespaces, runtime

I'm using Clojure to write a small test framework.

```
(ns pvt.core.runner
  (use 
    [pvt.tests.deployment]
    [pvt.tests.files]
    [pvt.tests.jms]))

(defn- run-test
  [test-name]
  {test-name (test-and-log test-name)})

(defn- run-all-tests-in-namespace
  [namespace-name]
  (map
    run-test
    (vals (ns-publics (symbol namespace-name))))
  )

(defn run-all-tests
  [namespace-list]
  (map run-all-tests-in-namespace namespace-list))
```

My `run-all-tests` function accepts a list of clojure scripts, loads all the public functions in those scripts and runs them. This is great, only that i have to actually import those scripts. I call my function like this `(run-all-tests ["pvt.tests.deployment" "pvt.tests.files" "pvt.tests.jms"])`, but this only works if I import each of these scripts as seen at the beginning of my code excerpt. This is not ok, since I hvae no idea who will call run-all-tests, and what parameters will be used.

I was wondering if there's a way of importing these scripts at runtime. I already know the namespace of each script, so I have all the required information. Can this be done? 
Thanks

Comment: Namespaces are first class citizens. I don't see what your problem is. See: http://clojure.org/namespaces and http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/use

Comment: Well, namespaces are first class citizens, but the techniques needed to do what sebi wants may not be so obvious to beginners. Please see my answer and comment appropriately (especially any feedback on how I map and filter the namesapces).

Comment: Your answer is very good and comprehensive, however I guessed that all which was required was to call (use ...) inside the function. The answer from OP confirms this was the case.

Comment: 1) `use` is now widely discouraged. 2) "this only works if I import each of these scripts as seen at the beginning of my code excerpt. This is not ok..." - OP didn't want to have namespace names hard-coded in the source, that's what I answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for helping me out. I managed to find what I was looking for. It was actually simpler than I thought. Didn't know that `use` is actually a function. Now i simply do this:

```
(defn- run-all-tests-in-namespace
  [namespace-name]
  (use (symbol namespace-name))
  (map
    run-test
    (vals (ns-publics (symbol namespace-name))))
  )
```

I create a symbol from the namespace name and then pass it to the `use` function. Works great!

Comment: Hah, really? Your question stated you were creating a framework, and didn't want to hard-code namespace names.

Comment: I don't. run-all-tests is a public method and and it will receive the namespace names from the callers.

Comment: Ok, well, you should prefer `(require)` with `:refer [test-fns...]` instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358149/in-clojure-1-4-what-is-the-use-of-refer-within-require - I don't think you really want to use `use`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can import Clojure source files from arbitrary file paths using `load-file`. If the source file contains a namespace declaration, those namespaces are now available to your Clojure application (framework).

Obviously, at a minimum you'll have to write some code that either takes names of Clojure source files from the command-line, or points to directories where the source files are located. Then your code will load the files using `(load-file)`.

Your stated problem is that you want to execute some tests from the namespace without knowing the namespace names in advance. There are two ways to achieve this:

**1) Use a naming convention.** i.e. run your tests for each namespace that has the name matching your convention, i.e.

```
user=> (load-file "/home/noahlz/foo.clj") 
#<Var@1e955d29: #<core$foo foo.test.core$foo@48a7a9bd>>
user=> (filter #(re-matches #".*\.test\..*" %) (map str (all-ns)))
("foo.test.core")
```

Using code like the above, you've obtained a list of namespaces upon which you can execute your framework code.

**2) Use metadata.**  Rather than follow a naming convention, require users of your framework to add metadata to their namespaces. This reduces the chance of accidentally testing a namespace that accidentally followed your convention.

(See: [What are some uses of Clojure metadata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175258/what-are-some-uses-of-clojure-metadata))

Note that this is the approach used by Clojure's own `clojure.test/deftest` macro.

Here is an example of finding namespaces with your custom metadata. Your namespace declaration in a source file defining tests:

```
(ns ^{:doc "some documentation" :my-framework-tests true}
  foo.test.core)
```

At the REPL, an example of how you can obtain these programmatically:

```
user=> (load-file "foo.clj")

user=> (filter (fn [[n m]] (:my-framework-tests m)) 
               (map #(vector (str %) (meta %)) (all-ns)))
(["foo.test.core" {:my-framework-tests true, :doc "some documentation"}])
```

Now you have a list of namespaces that have been flagged as containing tests for your custom test framework. You could even use metadata in the namespace functions to avoid needing a naming convention for those as well.

There might be a more concise way to obtain namespaces having certain metadata (if someone knows of it, by all means, comment!)

Another important note: I'm loading arbitrary files to demonstrate it's possible, buy you really should consider following conventions followed by Leiningen, Maven or other build frameworks. For example, see [lein-perforate](https://github.com/davidsantiago/perforate)

Good luck!